TypeError when trying to setPreferredAlgorithms
I am having issues with the following code. This is just the pre-login section.  The way this used to work was, I get the key from a file. create a new sftp object, set the preferred algorithm to ssh-dss (which is the only algorithm this particular server offers) and then login. And all was fine. I must have updated something on the server that botched things because the code didn't change but this bit is now broken.
I keep getting this error:
array_intersect(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given 
We're using PHP 8.0.30
PHPSECLIB 3.0
On Ubuntu 20.04.6
Apache 2.4.62
I've seen similar issues with WordPress but nothing that would give me a solution.
If you are able to help me solve this I would be very grateful.

$key = $this->__getKeyWithFile($mykey, $myphrase);
$sftp = new SFTP($host, $port);
if (!empty($sftp)) {
  try {
    $sftp->setPreferredAlgorithms(['hostkey' => 'ssh-dss']);
    $sftp->login($user, $key)
  } catch (Error $er) {
     echo $er->getMessage();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
     echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
}


EDITED TO ADD full error. My bad. However the problem is solved below.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_intersect(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:4623
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(4623): array_intersect()
#1 FTPTools.php(105): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->setPreferredAlgorithms()
#2 Reporter.php(1247): FTPTools->login()
#3 run_rebot.php(60): Reporter->myfunction()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 4623

I tried updating my server. I tried re-installing phpseclib. Neither worked.

@DarkBee Because they are passing an incorrect type, and that's what the error says. Unless they changed the title.
But yes, as DarkBee said...show the full error object, so we can take a look at the array_intersect you're getting an error on. You can do so yourself and then just dump the value. Or install XDebug!

@PaulAllsopp They didn't change the title no, but it seems that array_intersect throws a TypeError (PHP 8+) rather than a warning

@DarkBee it is an incorrect type, so it throw a TypeError. This bypasses the warning thrown by the function. The function must evaluate to get the warning. Because of the type error, it cannot evaluate.

The point being, in a compiled language this would be equivalent to a compile-time error, not a runtime error. The code cannot even run, so it cannot evaluate the function

There's no call to array_intersect in the code provided in the question. So we can't see what you've passed to it, or where. The stack trace on the error should show exactly what line, in what file, it originated. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. If the issue is within a 3rd-party library you've installed, please make sure you're using a version of the library which is supported on the version of PHP you're using.

I must have updated something on the server...so, go back through any server changes or udpdates you've made recently, and see if anything stands out.

You're doing this:
$sftp->setPreferredAlgorithms(['hostkey' => 'ssh-dss']);

When you should be doing this:
$sftp->setPreferredAlgorithms(['hostkey' => ['ssh-dss']]);


Good catch. You'd like to think the function would validate the format of the input data before proceeding, but apparently not!

THANK YOU! I had been staring at this too long. That did the trick.

@ADyson But the function did validate, found a type error, and kicked out the exception.
The function running was negated by the type error...it couldn't even try to run. Like a compile-time vs run-time error. A runtime error means the compiler passed validation. In this case it wasn't even possible to compile it...that needed to be solved first. I know PHP is not compiled; I'm just using that as an analogy.

@PaulAllsopp I meant that setPreferredAlgorithms should validate the input. Instead it passed part of it to array_intersect even though it was a string, and this caused the crash. A nicer API interface to the library would refuse to continue the function or call anything else if the input isn't structured correctly. It would be easier for calling code to understand what was wrong rather than debugging internals of the library. But it's not essential

@ADyson Yes, I do agree. They could easily have bumped validation up and not ever let it get to that point. Sorry if I misinterpreted what you said.

@PaulAllsopp no problem, I probably wasn't as clear as I could have been
